# Bug which mistakenly accuses the writer for shouting and issues a warning

Tags: discussion, quality-filter, regex

Today, while typing an answer on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com), I needed to use the factorial expression. While typing in my answer, I received the following warning:

> DON'T SHOUT! All-caps posts are considered rude and will quickly be deleted.

[image: screenshot of math formula]

Surprisingly, there were no letters in my answer, yet it warned me about typing in capitals.

**Discuss (if possible)**: the mechanism of the CAPS detection function.

**Bug to be fixed**: training the algorithm to read for real alphabets instead of the number of exclamation marks.

Further research (on Chemistry, Physics and primary Meta):  it was found that none of them really respond to caps or the above expression. For that reason, I checked my bug again on Math.SE, and it worked again.

Exact code:

```
$ 100! - 101! + ... - 109! + 110! $
```

Reference:

1. [Chemistry​](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CbPq.png)
2. [Primary Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qouib.png)
3. [Math Meta Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/dont-shout-warning-without-capitals)

The third reference linked is stuck at evaluation and the bug has not been fixed. As per a comment :

This is caused by a blacklist entry for pattern ^(?-i:\P{Ll}+){15,}$, which matches 15 or more consecutive non-lowercase characters. Too bad you can't just use ^(?-i:\p{Lu}+){15,}$, since spaces and punctuation should not be considered to break the consecutive count. – Chris Jester-Young

The above report is definitely not valid now, look below:

[image]

looking at the above, please note there is a small ***a***. Now look at the below one:

[image]

Now since it looks like it must be networkwide, here is an example of meta-stackexchange:

[image]

---

**Update:**  After a bit of research on the S.E. network, I could not find any documentation to the warning triggered by the system. So before flagging a [bug] I would like to discuss **how is the feature implemented** and **why is it site specific**, i.e. only implemented on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) and not on the sites namely physics, chemistry, meta stackexchange. The purpose of asking why is it site specific is that as far as I know, the backend code which can trigger such features makes it apply to the whole network.

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1521/discussion-on-question-by-queenie-goldstein-bug-which-mistakenly-accuses-the-wri).